# display elements of two lists by value of third list python

Tags: python, list

Goal: iterate over lst1 and lst2 and display only the values where value of lst_msk equal to 1. All values of lst1 and lst2 at the indices where lst_msk is 0 should be ignored

example:

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst_msk = [1,1,1,0,0]
```

my approach:

```
for i in lst1:
    for j in lst2:
       # couldn't figure out the remaining part yet
```

Desired Output:

```
1 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 3 2 3 3
```

Comment: sorry, desired output should be: 1 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 3 2 3 3

Comment: please explain your output. How do you get 1 1 1 2 in the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over "parallel" lists:

```
for v1, v2, msk in zip(lst1, lst2, lst_mask):
   ..
```

(if all lists are to be iterated simultaneously) or

```
for v1, msk1 in zip(lst1, lst_mask):
   for v2, msk2 in zip(lst2, lst_mask):
       ...
```

(if all `lst1` and `lst2` are to be iterated independently).

Answer (score 4):

You might use `zip` for that task as follows:

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst_msk = [1,1,1,0,0]
for l1, l2, lm in zip(lst1,lst2,lst_msk):
    if lm == 1:
        print(l1,l2)
```

output

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) is handy when you need to deal with corresponding elements of list of equal length.

Comment: sorry, desired output should be: 1 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 3 2 3 3

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple solution:

```py
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst_msk = [1,1,1,0,0]

for index, item in enumerate(lst_msk):
    if item == 1:
        print(lst1[index], lst2[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a quadratic loop. The solution like that works as you wanted:

```py
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst_msk = [1,1,1,0,0]

for i in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst_msk[i] == 1:
        print(lst1[i], lst2[i])
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehention and `zip` for this.
`zip` returned i - (lst1), j - (lst2), k - (lst_msk) values and you can filter it with `if`. But in this case you should know about specific `zip` function :

```
print(*[f"{i} {j}" for i,j,k in zip(lst1,lst2, lst_msk) if k != 0], sep="\n")
```

output:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```